# What is the acceptable resistance of a functioning heater cartridge on my Creality Ender-5 Pro printer?

Tags: creality-ender-5, thermal-runaway

It has been suggested that I measure the resistance of the nozzle heater on my printer since I've had some thermal runaway errors. The machine is brand new. I have done so by connecting my multimeter across the two pins on the connector. I get a value of 14.5 Ohms. Is this a reasonable value?

Answer (score 1):

Your printer uses a 24 V power supply, this implies that the peripherals also need to be for this voltage. Therefor a 24 V heater cartridge is needed.

From [this answer](/a/9951/) on question [Heater cartridge with 7.2 ohms - 12 or 24 V?](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/9947/heater-cartridge-with-7-2-ohms-12-or-24-v) gives you the answer:

> e3D Heater Cartridges are documented to be around 4.8 Ω for 12 V & 30 W, 3.6 Ω for 12 V & 40 W, 19.2 Ω for 24 V 30 W and 14.4 Ω for 24 V 40 W.

A heater cartridge of 14.5 Ω is a 24 V heater cartridge of 40 W, this is the correct heater cartridge for your printer.